# How to encrypt the DB password in Artifactory?

Tags: encryption, passwords, artifactory

We have Artifactory OSS that currently use the default DB and we want to move to MS-SQL.  According to the regular links - we need to write the MSSQL password in clear text in the db.properties file.

Can the password be encrypted somehow, so the Artifactory will know how to decrypt and use it

Comment: You should be able to encrypt the password before you store it, then encrypt the user's entered password and compare both encrypted strings against each other. If the user entered the correct password, the output should be identical.

Comment: I am confused, I expected recent versions of Artifactory to activate encryption by default and to rewrite the password into an encrypted password on first start. Can you actually start Artifactory and check if the password gets encrypted?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to activate encryption using the REST API. See the [documented API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ActivateArtifactoryKeyEncryption).

This should create an encryption key and apply it on the **db.properties** where the username and password are stored.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

What I found was that after switching to MS-SQL and starting Artifactory- Artifactory has encrypted the password.

In the admin->Security->Security Configuration there is a section for Password encryption that you can choose to encrypt all password in configuration files